# Simple Chrome Extension but Issues?

Tags: javascript, json, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Ave!

Dear People..

I wanted to make an extension of my "Google Custom Search Code"

to show search results from my website in Extension Popup (popup.html)

I am having issues while making an extension from it.

1. When I load iframe from local computer The popup is showing Text but the Search Dialog box is not showing.
2. When I load iframe from GoogleDrive iframe is showing but it takes nearly 3 4 seconds to load.
3. ------------------ (No. 3 I solved successfully)
   The Links are not opening in new tab I treid too much please help me to open link in new tab??
   (in Google Search API there was an option Search Features> Advance > Target Link ... I put the value _Blank)

Thanks alot!

The codes are as below.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Instant Search!",
    "description": "Search My Blog Instantly!",

    "version": "0.1",
   "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Search My Blog"
    }

}
```

Popup.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="400" height="400" 
             seamless="seamless"src="/QS.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

iframe page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<style>
.cse input.gsc-input, input.gsc-input {
background-image:url('/blank.gif')!important;
}
</style> 
  </head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '009043611225946488903:ntz9nyqubzw';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Two possible problems: 1) inline script in your iframe (move it into a separate `foo.js` and include it with `<script src="foo.js">`, and 2) including a script over HTTP instead of HTTPS, which I think is disallowed by Chrome's default CSP (so change your conditional to use HTTPS by default -- a protocol of `chrome-extension:` triggers  HTTP loading).

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't have script tags in your HTML code (so `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]` doesn't exists)

Try :

```
document.body.appendChild(gcse);
```

instead of :

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
```

Comment: Nothing Happened bro by channing it? what was the expected BTW? its same as before no errors no improvemnts